# dotnet restore not creating bin when multiple solution files are present in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, intellisense

I have an application that includes two `.csproj` files and two `.sln` file, one for each `.csproj`. When I run `dotnet restore program_one.sln` it creates a `bin` and `obj` folder as expected. However when I run `dotnet restore program_two.sln` it only creates the `obj` folder, and without the `bin` my intellisense fails as do most of the plugins I have installed.

I have opened this project in visual studio and both solutions are loaded without issue and intellisense works without issue.

If I remove `program_one.sln` and then restore `program_two.sln`, it will contain a `bin` file and everything works as expected. Is this simply something that is not supported in VS Code? Do I need to make changes to my `launch.json` or my `tasks.json`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a solution for each project, instead of a single solution for both projects?

Comment: We want to be able to have separate nuget releases for each project, but have them both stored in the same repository. I have my doubts about if it's the right path, but now I'm just curious how to get it set up correctly

Comment: I see, I've recently been battling with the proper workflow for a similar solution-related issue. Are both solutions in the same directory? Or maybe try using a third solution for development purposes that includes both projects?

Comment: The `bin` folder shouldn't be created by `dotnet restore`, is this omnisharp / while vs code is open? omnisharp can only load one .sln file and you can use omnisharp commands via Ctrl+Shift+P/CMD+Shift+P to tell it to load a different solution.

Comment: ah ha! that's the issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found:**

The issue ended up having nothing to do `dotnet restore` at all, but rather omnisharp which is what creates the bin folders. Omnisharp can only load one solution file, so ultimately this scenario is one that will cause some issues.

using omnisharp commands via `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`/`CMD`+`Shift`+`P`, you can tell it to load a different solution with the `OmniSharp: Select Project` command.